# GitLab and 2FA on windows 10

Tags: gitlab

I need to setup 2FA with gitlab but I don't have android or iOS device. 
I want to setup it on my Windows 10 development machine.
Is any program on windows 10 that supports 2FA and GitLab?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! 
https://github.com/winauth/winauth
The best! Works with gitlab perfectly!